# How do I update local repo with "no changes" (End of line issue)

Tags: python, git, core.autocrlf

I work in a team in which everyone except me is working with Mac. I'm working with Windows 10.
I cloned the remote team repository and worked with it, when we realized there were problems with CRLF.
I changed a git option but now I want to update again the repo but no changes it's detected so I don't know how to bring the same text that I have with the correct line end in all repository files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried git checkout -- ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, literally, to remove all the files and then check them out again:

```
git rm -r -- .          # remove everything
git checkout HEAD -- .  # check everything out again
```

(Side note: the example here uses `--`, which isn't required for the name `.`: it's only needed if your file name looks like a branch name or a command option.  It's a good habit to get into using it all the time, so that if you want to check out a file named `master` later, you just automatically write `git checkout -- master` and don't accidentally write `git checkout master`, which obviously does something different.)

#### Why you need to remove first

There's a rather basic Git annoyance here, which is that Git tries to be efficient.  Using a slightly shorter command, `git checkout -- .`, would otherwise do just what you want, but Git compares what's in your index / staging-area / cache<sup>1</sup> to what's in your work-tree.  Git uses the "cache" aspect of the index to speed this up a lot, by knowing that the index is indexing/cacheing the work-tree content so that if nothing has changed in the index and work-tree, the work-tree version of each and every file automatically correctly matches the index version of that same file.

The short description of the index is that it is *where you build up your next commit*.  This is why it has the name *staging area:* you "stage" files into it, and when you make the commit, the new commit uses whatever is on this stage to take the snapshot.  It's basically *never* empty, though (except after our `git rm -r -- .` above!): it starts out holding *every file that is in the current commit*.  Later, you will use `git add` to *replace* the index version of the file with a newer version.

Git is mostly about commits, and each commit stores a complete snapshot of every file—not changes since a previous version, just the whole file, intact but compressed.  The copies that are in commits are in this special compressed Git-only format and are *read only* as they can *never be changed*.  The copy in the index is literally, initially, just a replaceable version of the copy that's in the commit, stored using just a few dozens of bytes because it really *is* the version in the commit, until you overwrite the index copy with a new version.  The index copy is therefore also in the special Gitty format, useless to most programs, good only for Git itself.

Hence, what you *work* with is files in your *work-tree*, so named because it's a directory tree (a directory or folder with sub-directories or sub-folders, all of which contains files) where you do your work.  Git extracts files from a commit into the index, so that they can be replaced, and then extracts the files from the index to the work-tree, so that they can be expanded into useful format.

Here's the tricky part: **All special end of line handling occurs when files go from the index to the work-tree, or from the work-tree to the index.**  So `git checkout -- <file>`, which extracts one file from the index to the work-tree, re-does the end-of-line handling when creating the file you will work with.  Your eventual `git add -- <file>` will undo any special end-of-line handling when compressing the file into the special Git-only format to stuff it into the index.

But as noted above, **Git tries to be efficient.**  The index holds not just a copy of the file, but also information *about* the file, to help Git quickly figure out whether there is any difference between the copy in the index and the copy in the work-tree.  If Git has just *checked out* the file, Git *knows for certain* that the copy in the work-tree *matches* the copy in the index.

If you *change your end of line handling,* you change the *way* Git will extract a file from the index to the work-tree.  That means that the copy in the work-tree is no longer valid.  This is just where the annoyance comes in: *Git doesn't realize that the work-tree copy is no longer valid.  It thinks it's still a perfect match, and doesn't bother extracting the file again so as to avoid wasting time.*

This wastes *your* time, because now you have to do something (such as remove the file) just to get Git to do something (re-extract the file).  The `git rm -r -- .` removes *every* file, from both the work-tree *and* the index, that is in your current directory/folder (`.`), and then the `git checkout HEAD -- .` re-extracts every such file from the current commit into the index and on into the work-tree.  This obeys the new end-of-line setting and gets you the files in the form you want.

You only need to do this when you change the end-of-line settings when you're initially setting Git up.  So this is kind of a one-time deal—it's not as painful as this description makes it sound.  But I would argue that it *is* a bug.

---

<sup>1</sup>These are three different names for one thing, which reflect its enormous importance (it *is* very important), or its multiple different roles (it has several roles), or is because the first name that was used, "index", is such a bad name. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the lessons. I'll try it on Monday.
That's supposed to do it at every branch I want to update? Because a  later merge of master branch into another branch maybe doesn't work because of the 'no changes detected'. That's it?

Comment: @borjaperez: your comment implies that you still have not got into your head how Git actually works (this is not surprising, as it's very tricky). The key insight here is that, for end-of-line manipulation, *branch names don't matter* and in fact not even *commits* matter much: only the difference, if any, between the contents of the *index* vs the contents of the *work-tree*, as controlled by end-of-line settings, matters. You would probably benefit a lot from a good Git book or tutorial, since this part happens after the important parts about commits and branch names.